# I want to find the missing values for the second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

table 1 example:

```
id | name
 1 | John
 2 | Mary
```

table 2 example:

```
personId | groupID
   1     |  3
   1     |  5
   2     |  5
   2     |  7
```

every person should be into groups 3,5 and 7 for this example, how can i find every user and its missing groups?

Comment: Do you know all the groups?  That is, some solutions cannot gove the 'right' answer if _everyone_ is missing from some group.

Comment: yes, I know all the groups, but in this case I have people in every group I am trying to find

Comment: Finding the users in all groups is easy and quite different than finding which groups a user is not in.  Which do you want?

Comment: I want to find the specific groups each user is not in

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify that this gets all 6 combinations:

```
SELECT personId, groupId
    FROM ( SELECT 3 AS groupId UNION ALL
           SELECT 5 AS groupId UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 AS groupId )  AS AllGroups
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT personId
            FROM table2 ) AS AllPersons
```

Now, let's see the 2 rows missing from table2:

```
SELECT personId, groupId
    FROM ( the above query ) AS AllPairs
    LEFT JOIN table2 USING(personId, groupId)
    WHERE table2.personId IS NULL
```